# Akka-streams: How-to connect a stream to a stream?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

If a Flow A produces

```
Pair<Source<ByteString,?>, Object>
```

How do I connect this outlet with Flow B's inlet which maps on the Source. For example Flow B's outlet would be

```
Pair<InputStream<Long>,Object>.
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. By InputStream you mean java.io.InputStream? What's the purpose of the Pair? You want to connect an Akka stream to an Akka stream? Or an Akka Source to a java.io.InputStream?

Comment: take for example a akka-http-pool flow it produces a reponse.get().entity().getDataBytes() so your stream is now  source-flow-source. now my sink wants to produce json with ObjectMapper.read(InputStream). Of course i could meteralize in between but this kind of contradicts streams

Comment: What is "akka-http-pool"? Maybe I just still don't understand what you mean, but... what you described is not Source -> Flow -> Source, it is a source of sources, or Source<Source<ByteString, _>, _>. What you need to do is attach a Sink<Source<ByteString, _>, _> which will consume the ByteString sources. The sink can then attach each of the received sources to some ByteString sink and run it.

Comment: Or you can flatten the original Sink<Source<ByteString, _>, _> to a Source<ByteString, _> by using the flatten method, with a concat FlattenStrategy. But this seems like a wrong approach.

Comment: http-pool is http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/java/http/client-side/request-level.html#flow-based-variant

Comment: the problem with  Sink<Source<ByteString, _>, _> is that in the sink I then need to consume the source. don't I now loose the backpressure wiring that streams buy me? ( I'll check if flatten helps me)

Comment: No, you don't loose backpressure. No reason to loose backpressure. You just get one "top level" stream and multiple "low level" streams. The top level stream handles new connections and the low level streams handle data coming through the connections. If you flatten it, you basically mix all data from all the connections together. Which could be what you want, or not.

Comment: @quizzle  I can't flatten because each connection is a seperate payload/message. But I think your're right I don't loose backbackpressure.

Comment: But I think your're right I don't loose backpressure. so I just start new streams from the given sink sources. It does look unusual though

Comment: I'm pretty sure flattening would work. Each "message" represents one new connection and contains a source of ByteStrings. Flattening with concat would create a stream where the first ByteString source would be drained til finish, then the next one, then the next...

Comment: no I checked concat does nor work because it would spoil concurrency . I need merge https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/15089

Comment: Of course it spoils concurrency. That's why is said it was a wrong approach and probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are given a Source of the type you provided:

```
Source< Pair<Source<ByteString, BoxedUnit>, Object>, BoxedUnit> pairSource;
```

And you're also given a flow that converts `ByteString` values to `InputStream<Long>`:

```
Flow<ByteString, InputStream<Long>, ?> byteStrToInputStream;
```

Then this can be transformed using flatMapConcat:

```
Source< Pair<InputStream<Long>,Object>, BoxedUnit> inputStreamSource = 
  pairSource.flatMapConcat( pair -> {
    pair.getKey()
        .via(byteStrToInputStream)
        .map(inputStream -> ImmutablePair(inputStream, pair.getValue()))
  })
```

Each one of the incoming Sources of ByteStrings is exhausted and the results are concatenated.  The original right side of each pair, namely `Object` is added to each InputStream.